# Python 2d Interpolation Problems

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I currently have three 1D numpy arrays like so:

```
#X     Y     Z
 0     1     2.9
 0     3     2.1
 0     5     1.753
 .     .     .
 .     .     .
 0     99    3.82
 0.1   1     4.1
 0.1   3     5.3
 0.1   5     2.65
 .     .     .
 .     .     .
 0.1   99    5.21
```

Each z corresponds to the (x,y) pair at that same index.  I am trying to perform linear interpolation on my grid, so that I am able to see what the value of Z is at say (57.3, 33.1).

My problem is that my X values are going all the way up to almost 100 in increments of 0.1, and my Y values are incrementing by 2.  When I try to interpolate with interp2d or bisplrep, I always get a segmentation fault. (I'm assuming because of the amount of data points?).

Any help you can provide is appreciated.  My X coordinates are incrementing by a small enough amount that I will never try to check a Z value at say (50.53,y).  I do need to be able to check the Y values at that increment though.  For example (50.1, 33.6).

I built a dictionary of (x,y) coordinates and their corresponding z value if that is of use.

Edit:

Since I already have Z values for each (x,y) pair, I do not see why the following code wouldn't work (it seg faults after about 20 seconds).

```
f = interpolate.interp2d(X, Y, Z, kind='linear')
```

Since I already have X and Y structured like this, I don't need to use np.meshgrid to build a grid.  Is that correct?

Comment: `interp2d` should be exactly what you want.  Can you post the code you tried?

Comment: When trying to reproduce the error my computer just worked on it for a long time until I gave up on waiting and killed it. But doing the same for a smaller set worked fine. To do linear interpolation the b-spline control points are equal to the interpolation points so you can do this manually with very little code and just use your current data.

Comment: You want `RectBivariateSpline`. Using a scattered data interpolation algorithm (such as interp2d has) is inefficient if your data actually has a regular structure. (Segfaulting is of course a bug, though.)